# Compatibility with 105 shifters

Tags: road

Can I use Deore RD-T610-SGS derailleur on my road bike with 105 shifters, it seems like cable pull isn't right. Shifters are on 2007 Specialized Roubaix compact.

Comment: Sheldon brown's site contains a lot of information on compatability - another issue is cassettee - so prob easiest to start there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shimano 10 speed mountain rear derailleurs or 11 speed road derailleurs work with Shimano 11 speed road shifters.

Shimano 7,8,9,10 speed road and 7,8,9 speed mountain derailleurs work with Shimano 7,8,9,10 speed road shifters in terms of cable pull.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I use a 9-speed mount derailleur (deore xt) on a 10 speed cassette (11-32) with a 10 speed road shifter (105) and a triple (50/36/30).  The cable pull is fine.  The capacity is just OK.  It took some b-screw adjustment to get it working well.

It turns out there are many people doing the same thing, especially on tandems.

This fits what you said - but it is notable that one can still run a 10 speed mountain >cassette< with a 10 speed road shifter.